# Kangaroo paw dying

Tags: diagnosis

I've planted a kangaroo paw a few weeks ago. However, it has been slowly loosing leaves (they become brown and dry) since then and almost all its flowers have wilted. I have been watering it regularly about 3 times per week so I don't think that is the problem. What can I do to save it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: definitely stop watering. in Australia they aren't watered at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to chop the whole plant off about 1" above the ground. Watch to make sure you don't cut off any emerging new fans. Each fan, after producing one flower stalk, will not then produce another. Like an orchid.
2. Give it a bit of fertiliser maybe for native plants.
3. If it is really hot, and it looks like they are in a hot place, water 3 times a week in the summer will help them get established.
   Stay green